# точка входа в процедуру SetDefaultDllDirectories не найдена в библиотеке DLL KERNEL32.dll

Tags: windows

При установке сторонних программ с официальных сайтов (Atom -редактор кода или Figma ) Выдаёт ошибку "точка входа в процедуру SetDefaultDllDirectories не найдена в библиотеке DLL KERNEL32.dll". Как это исправить и наконец установить нужные приложения ?
ПО : Windows7

[image: окно с ошибкой]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно обновить Windows. [В документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-setdefaultdlldirectories) о функции `SetDefaultDllDirectories` сказано:

> **KB2533623** must be installed on the target platform.